# JavaFX check what's under MouseClick

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, drag-and-drop, mouseevent

I have `ArrayList<ImageView> imageViews = new ArrayList<>();` and so it contains images.
Images are created on button click, saved to that array and appears on scene from that array. Code is somewhat messy, but hey, #makeItWork at first #makeItRight later...

```
    public void btnAddAndAction() throws FileNotFoundException {
        algorithm.addElement(algorithm.calculateId(),"AND",null);
        imageViews.add(new ImageView(algorithm.getLastElementImg()));
                imageViews.get(imageViews.size()-1).setX(25); //default pos
                imageViews.get(imageViews.size()-1).setY(85);
                pane.getChildren().add( imageViews.get(imageViews.size()-1));
                pane.requestLayout();
    imageViews.get(imageViews.size()-1).setOnMousePressed(imgOnMousePressedEventHandler);
           imageViews.get(imageViews.size()-1).setOnMouseDragged(imgOnMouseDraggedEventHandler);
            }


    //FIXME
    EventHandler<MouseEvent> imgOnMousePressedEventHandler =
            new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

                @Override
                public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
                    orgSceneX = t.getSceneX();
                    orgSceneY = t.getSceneY();
                    orgTranslateX = ((imageViews.get(imageViews.size()-1)).getTranslateX());
                    orgTranslateY = ((imageViews.get(imageViews.size()-1)).getTranslateY());
                }
            };
//FIXME
    EventHandler<MouseEvent> imgOnMouseDraggedEventHandler =
            new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

                @Override
                public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
                    double offsetX = t.getSceneX() - orgSceneX;
                    double offsetY = t.getSceneY() - orgSceneY;
                    double newTranslateX = orgTranslateX + offsetX;
                    double newTranslateY = orgTranslateY + offsetY;

                    (imageViews.get(imageViews.size()-1)).setTranslateX(newTranslateX);
                    (imageViews.get(imageViews.size()-1)).setTranslateY(newTranslateY);
                }
            };
```

I'm trying to do drag and drop feature to the images and I am struggling to detect what's under mouse...

I've fount `getSource` from `MouseEvent`, but it needs object...

so: how do I know, which element of array is pressed so I could drag it??

Java 1.8, JavaFX, IntelliJ.

Comment: Create a different handler for each image

Comment: Also I'm not really sure what the problem is with using `getSource()`... What do you mean "it needs object"?

Comment: I mean that I need to pass object to it, not ImageView... Btw, about different handler for each image: you mean put it also in list or some kind of array and have separate one for every element in image list? Asking just to make it sure... Sounds like it might get it to work, 'cause now it's always moving the last element of list, even if I am trying to drag another picture.

Comment: An `ImageView` _is an_ `Object`. If the `EventHandler` was added to the `ImageView` then the source of `MouseEvent`, while being handled by that `EventHandler`, is the `ImageView`. Just cast the result of `getSource()`.

Comment: Oh, _cast_, right... It works perfectly now, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to *CAST* ImageView... Answer is in the comment section.